# How to handle network issue while developing an Android app which depends highly on internet

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I am trying to develop an Android application for social networking.

It has many activity, fragments adapters and many more

I don't want to do check internet from NetworkManager in every one of them Everytime

I want a way in which I can implement the network failed cases smoothly and easily

I have checked how to use Network Manger to get network state and it is connected to internet or not .

I have also checked Broadcast receiver and it is more usefully then Network Manger and close match to what I imagine.

Is there any better way to tackle this problem.
Also how can we deal with slow connected problem.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should handle network process in background thread. There are some options :

Asynctask : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

or you can use RxJava, but it's a little bit harder

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OkHttpClient you can use an interceptor.

Define the http client like this with its interceptor that throws NoInternetException

```java
OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        httpClient.connectTimeout(HTTP_CLIENT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        httpClient.readTimeout(HTTP_CLIENT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        httpClient.writeTimeout(HTTP_CLIENT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {

            @Override
            public okhttp3.Response intercept (@NonNull Chain chain) throws
            NoInternetException, InterceptorException
            {

                if (!Util.isNetworkAvailable(mContext)) {
                    throw new NoInternetException();
                }
            }
        });
```

With this helper function you can detect if network is available:

```java
  public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = null;
        if (connectivityManager != null) {
            activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        }
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
```

Let me know if this helps ;)